# Добавление элемента в select

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, fontawesome

Добрый вечер!

Как добавить вот такую стрелочку в select?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предпочтение - FontAwesome. Через Background не выйдет, т.к фон самого Select'а задан через него, через after вообще ничего не появляется...

CSS разметка:

```
  select {
    width: 225px;
    height: 55px;
    padding: 0 15px 2.5px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 40px 10px 15px 10px;
    font-family: GothamL;
    background: url("../img/searchselect.png");
    border: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    &:after {
      content: "▼";
      padding: 0 8px;
      font-size: 12px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 8px;
      top: 4px;
      z-index: 1;
      text-align: center;
      width: 10%;
      height: 100%;
      pointer-events: none;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <select class="selection">
     <option>Dubai</option>
     <option>Dubai</option>
     <option>Dubai</option>
     <option>Dubai</option>
     <option>Dubai</option>
     <option>Dubai</option>
     <option>Dubai</option>
     <option>Dubai</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

* {
  outline: none;
}

.select-box {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 40px 10px 15px 10px;
}

.select-box:after {
  content: "▼";
  color:#fff;
  padding: 0 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top:-7px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

select {
  width: 225px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 0 15px 2.5px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: GothamL;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-radius: 28px;
  border: #fff solid 1px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

select option {
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-box">
  <select class="selection">
    <option>Dubai</option>
    <option>Dubai</option>
    <option>Dubai</option>
    <option>Dubai</option>
    <option>Dubai</option>
    <option>Dubai</option>
    <option>Dubai</option>
    <option>Dubai</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот пример для звездочек:

```
content: "\f005\f005\f005";
font-family: FontAwesome;
```